# How to handle NHibernate session lifetime using services?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, session, lazy-loading

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013467/what-should-be-the-lifetime-of-an-nhibernate-session) I asked about NHibernate session lifetime. I'm using a desktop application, but with client/server separation, so the conclusion is that I will use one session per server request, as the server side is where all the NHibernate magic happens.

My problem now is how to handle it. I've had [problems before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011950/nhibernate-mappings-issue-when-referencing-class-lazy-load-issue) with loading of referenced data when the session is prematurely closed. The problem is that I see the following on my referenced classes when debugging - hence the referenced data isn't loaded yet:

> base {NHibernate.HibernateException} = {"Initializing[MyNamespace.Foo#14]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: MyNamespace.Foo.Bars, no session or session was closed"}

From what I understand it doesn't load all even though I commit the transaction. So I've learned that I need to keep my session open for a while, but how long?

My question is basically if I'm handling the lifetime properly, or what  I should change to be on the right track. Honestly I can't see how this can be wrong, so what I'd really like is a function call to ensure that the referenced data is fetched. I'm *not* using lazy loading, so I thought they would be loaded immediately..?

Current architecture: Using a "service behavior" class that does the transaction. This is IDisposable, so the service itself it using a using-clause around it. The NHibernateSessionFactory provides a static factory which hence will be resused.

```
// This is the service - the function called "directly" through my WCF service. 
public IList<Foo> SearchForFoo(string searchString)
{
    using (var serviceBehavior = new FooServiceBehavior(new NhibernateSessionFactory()))
    {
        return serviceBehavior.SearchForFoo(searchString);    
    }                        
}

public class FooServiceBehavior : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public FooServiceBehavior(INhibernateSessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();                
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _session.Dispose();
    }

    public IList<Foo> SearchForFoo(string searchString)
    {           
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var result = _session.CreateQuery("from Foo where Name=:name").SetString("name", searchString).List<Name>();
            tx.Commit();
            return result; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I'm doing lazy loading after all. I had the following mapping:

```
public class FooMapping : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMapping()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("1");
        Map(c => c.Name).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
        HasMany(x => x.Bars).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

I assumed the `Not.LazyLoad()` disabled lazy loading, but apparently not for referenced objects. I added lazy loading on the reference, and this seems to have fixed the issue.

```
public class FooMapping : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMapping()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("1");
        Map(c => c.Name).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
        HasMany(x => x.Bars).Not.LazyLoad(); // <----------
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time, and I'll still be glad to see your opinions to whether my given structure is reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

If xml files are used for mapping purpose, we can set lazy=false for the bag.

Comment: XML files are not used for the mapping - as you can see in the example code. Am using Fluent for the mappings.